# VBA code to display multiple rows in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to display multiple rows with same name in Excel sheet that I have created using VBA code. I have created a textbox in my Excel sheet 1 and when I enter a name in the text box and click search button I want the multiple rows of the same person to be displayed in Excel sheet 3.

Code:
I have created the excel sheet called "List" and the data in there is

```
NAME     CITY

LAKHA   LONDON
KIKI    US
LAKHA   US
```

I have a code here.

```
Sub finddata()

Dim erow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim count As Integer

lastrow = Sheets("List").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 To lastrow
If Sheets("List").Cells(x, 1) = Sheet1.Range("E7") Then
Sheet3.Range("A2") = Sheets("List").Cells(x, 1)
Sheet3.Range("B2") = Sheets("List").Cells(x, 2)

End If

Next x

End Sub

Sub printdata()

Sheet3.Range("A1:B2").PrintPreview
'Sheet3.Range("A1:B2").PrintOut
End Sub

Sub Clear_Cells()

Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2:B2").ClearContents
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E7:E7").ClearContents

End Sub
```

But this only displays one row at a time.

Comment: Tip: from your question, delete "Immediate answers please. I am in deadline..."

Comment: You always write to cells A2 and B2. You are outputting all the required rows but all but the last are overwritten. Replace `Range("A2")` with `Cells(RowOut,1)`.  Replace `Range("B2")` with `Cells(RowOut,2)`.Add `RowOut = 2` before the loop and `RowOut = RowOut + 1` inside the loop before the `End If`.

Comment: `Immediate answers please. I am in deadline...` - oops - sorry - I wasn't awake when you posted - I guess there is now no use in my posting about  some of the other errors in your code because it is too late to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

also you should use .value after cell or range references i.e.

Sheet3.Range("A2").value = Sheets("List").Cells(x, 1).value

Comment: I consider including `Value` to be good practice but `Value` is the default property of `Range` so it is not essential.